# iOS: CLLocationManager's maximumRegionMonitoringDistance unit of measure

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager

I'm working with the CLLocationManager's maximumRegionMonitoringDistance property in iOS.  When I print this value out, I get 2,128,000, but I cannot find any documentation as to what unit of measurement this is in.  Any ideas?

2,128,000 seconds equates to ~591 degrees

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The documentation for `maximumRegionMonitoringDistance` shows:

> @property(readonly, nonatomic) CLLocationDistance maximumRegionMonitoringDistance

`CLLocationDistance` is defined in the [Core Location Data Types Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocationDataTypesRef/Reference/reference.html) as:

> A distance measurement (in meters) from an existing location.

Comment: I can't believe I missed that.  Thank you!